# Cannot prepare proper labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas

I have very simple code:

```
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
my_plot=df_h.boxplot(by='Day',figsize=(12,5), showfliers=False, rot=90)
```

I've got:
[image]

but I would like to have fewer labels on X axis. To do this I've add:

```
my_plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(12))
```

It generates fewer labels but values of labels have wrong values (=first of few labels from whole list)
What am I doing wrong?
[image]

I have add additional information:

I've forgoten to show what is inside DataFrame.
I have three columns:
 reg_Date - datetime64 (index)
 temperature - float64
 Day - date converted from reg_Date to string, it looks like '2017-10'  (YYYY-MM)

Box plot group date by 'Day' and I would like to show values 'Day" as a label but not all values
, for example every third one.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Just set [ticker.MultipleLocator](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator).

The [pandas.DataFrame.boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) also returns `axes`, which is an object of class `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. So you can use this code snippet to customize your labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

center = np.random.randint(50,size=(10, 20))
spread = np.random.rand(10, 20) * 30
flier_high = np.random.rand(10, 20) * 30 + 30
flier_low = np.random.rand(10, 20) * -30
y = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.boxplot(y)

x = ['Label '+str(i) for i in range(20)]
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.set_xlabel('Day')

# Set a tick on each integer multiple of a base within the view interval.
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: I've added additional information. Your solution is ok, but I would like to use values from last 'column' that coresponds to displayed values.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide sample code with data

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a compatibility issue with Pandas plots and Matplotlib formatters.

With the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('lt_stream-1001-full.csv', header=0, encoding='utf8')
df['reg_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reg_date'] , format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('reg_date', inplace=True)
df_h = df.resample(rule='H').mean()
df_h['Day']=df_h.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
print(df_h)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
my_plot = df_h.boxplot(by='Day',figsize=(12,5), showfliers=False, rot=90, ax=ax)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
i = 0
new_labels = list()
for l in labels:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        label = labels[i]
        i += 1
        new_labels.append(label)
    else:
        label = ''
        i += 1
        new_labels.append(label)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
plt.show()
```

You get this chart:
[image]
But I notice that this is grouped by month instead of by day. It may not be what you wanted.

Adding the day component to the string 'Day' messes up the chart as there seems to be too many boxes. 
[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv('lt_stream-1001-full.csv', header=0, encoding='utf8')
df['reg_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reg_date'] , format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('reg_date', inplace=True)
df_h = df.resample(rule='H').mean()
df_h['Day']=df_h.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df_h)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
my_plot = df_h.boxplot(by='Day',figsize=(12,5), showfliers=False, rot=90, ax=ax)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
i = 0
new_labels = list()
for l in labels:
    if i % 15 == 0:
        label = labels[i]
        i += 1
        new_labels.append(label)
    else:
        label = ''
        i += 1
        new_labels.append(label)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
plt.show()
```

The for loop creates the tick labels every as many periods as desired. In the first chart they were set every 3 months. In the second one, every 15 days.

If you would like to see less grid lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv('lt_stream-1001-full.csv', header=0, encoding='utf8')
df['reg_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reg_date'] , format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('reg_date', inplace=True)
df_h = df.resample(rule='H').mean()
df_h['Day']=df_h.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df_h)
f, ax = plt.subplots()
my_plot = df_h.boxplot(by='Day',figsize=(12,5), showfliers=False, rot=90, ax=ax)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
i = 0
new_labels = list()
new_locs = list()
for l in labels:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        label = labels[i]
        loc = locs[i]
        i += 1
        new_labels.append(label)
        new_locs.append(loc)
    else:
        i += 1       
ax.set_xticks(new_locs)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
ax.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I've read about x_compat in Pandas plot in order to apply Matplotlib formatters, but I get an error when trying to apply it. I'll give it another shot later.

**Old unsuccesful answer**

The tick labels seem to be dates. If they are set as datetime in your dataframe, you can:

```
months = mdates.MonthLocator(1,4,7,10) #Choose the months you like the most
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
```

Otherwise, you can let Matplotlib know they are dates by:

```
ax.xaxis_date()
```

**Your comment:**

*I have add additional information:*

*I've forgoten to show what is inside DataFrame.*
*I have three columns:*
 *reg_Date - datetime64 (index)*
 *temperature - float64*
 *Day - date converted from reg_Date to string, it looks like '2017-10'*  *(YYYY-MM) *

*Box plot group date by 'Day' and I would like to show values 'Day" as a* *label but not all values*
*, for example every third one.*

Based on your comment in italic above, I would use reg_Date as the input and the following lines:

```
days = mdates.DayLocator(interval=3)
daysFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m') #to format display
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(daysFmt)
```

I forgot to mention that you will need to:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
```

Does this work?

Comment: It does not work, no error but no label. But in your proposition you probably assume that on X axis I have date but  Day column is String in form of  eg, 2020-02, I have another column  reg_date but I group  rows by 'Day'

Comment: You can convert the string to date with pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], format='%Y-%m') and then work along. I find it always better to work with dates than string in charts.

Comment: Ok, I've tried but it works strange. I shared data+notebook here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cLeUxIqdhRYHjQGbZga5GgE8xy_0qs78    change last line from my_plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(30)) to e.g my_plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3)) and look at  values on x axis. It is not what I can expect.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I proposed a new possible way at the top of my old answer. Let me know if it works at all as intended

Comment: Thank you I will analyse this.